# How can I get output?

Tags: dictionary, tcl, procedure

Can anyone plz help me in understanding how I can get output in following manner using below code:

```
proc inrlist {args} {

    set result [list]
    foreach el $args {
    
        lappend result [expr 1 + "$el"]
    }
return $result
    
}
puts [inrlist 2 20 30 40]

proc map {f {args} } {
    
    set result1 [list]
    
    foreach el $args {
        
        lappend result1 [inrlist ["$el"]]
    }
    
}
set value [map 2 {34 45}]
puts $value
```

Expected output:

```
36 47
```

Comment: Your `map` proc should return something...

Comment: (among other issues)

Comment: The `map` proc has an argument `f` which isn't used.  

That proc also used square brackets incorrectly around `"$el"`.

Comment: Thank you Shawn and Chris for your suggestions. I have done the changes and the script is running now smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems. The main ones:

1. The `map` procedure you define does not actually return anything.
2. The code `["$el"]` is *extremely* unlikely to be doing what you want. Unless you want to execute a command called `34 43`. I doubt that a lot!

Here is a version that might be closer to what you expect:

```
proc map {f {args} } {
    set result1 [list]
    foreach el $args {
        lappend result1 [inrlist {*}$el]
    }
    return $result1
}
```

but we can replace that whole `map` with the built-in `lmap` command:

```
# I've split this over a few lines for clarity
set inputLists {2 {34 45}}
set value [lmap items $inputLists {
    inrlist {*}$items
}]
```